# Plot arbitrary paths with constant width given in data coordinates

Tags: python, matplotlib

### General aim

I am trying to write some plotting functionality that (at its core)
plots arbitrary paths with a constant width given in data coordinates
(i.e. unlike lines in matplotlib which have widths given in display coordinates).

### Previous solutions

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42972469/2912349) achieves
the basic goal. However, this answer converts between display and data
coordinates and then uses a matplotlib line with adjusted
coordinates. The existing functionality in my code that I would like
to replace / extend inherits from `matplotlib.patches.Polygon`. Since
the rest of the code base makes extensive use of
`matplotlib.patches.Polygon` attributes and methods, I would like to
continue to inherit from that class.

### Problem

My current implementation (code below) seems to come close. However,
the patch created by `simple_test` seems to be subtly thicker towards
the centre than it is at the start and end point, and I have no
explanation why that may be the case.

I suspect that the problem lies in the computation of the orthogonal vector.
As supporting evidence, I would like to point to the start and end points of the patch in the figure created by `complicated_test`, which do not seem exactly orthogonal to the path. However, the dot product of the orthonormal vector and the tangent vector is always zero, so I am not sure that what is going on here.

Output of `simple_test`:
[image]

Output of `complicated_test`:
[image]

### Code

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.patches
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class CurvedPatch(matplotlib.patches.Polygon):

    def __init__(self, path, width, *args, **kwargs):
        vertices = self.get_vertices(path, width)
        matplotlib.patches.Polygon.__init__(self, list(map(tuple, vertices)),
                                            closed=True,
                                            *args, **kwargs)

    def get_vertices(self, path, width):
        left = _get_parallel_path(path, -width/2)
        right = _get_parallel_path(path, width/2)
        full = np.concatenate([left, right[::-1]])
        return full


def _get_parallel_path(path, delta):
    # initialise output
    offset = np.zeros_like(path)

    # use the previous and the following point to
    # determine the tangent at each point in the path;
    for ii in range(1, len(path)-1):
        offset[ii] += _get_shift(path[ii-1], path[ii+1], delta)

    # handle start and end points
    offset[0] = _get_shift(path[0], path[1], delta)
    offset[-1] = _get_shift(path[-2], path[-1], delta)

    return path + offset


def _get_shift(p1, p2, delta):
    # unpack coordinates
    x1, y1 = p1
    x2, y2 = p2

    # get orthogonal unit vector;
    # adapted from https://stackoverflow.com/a/16890776/2912349
    v = np.r_[x2-x1, y2-y1]   # vector between points
    v = v / np.linalg.norm(v) # unit vector

    w = np.r_[-v[1], v[0]]    # orthogonal vector
    w = w / np.linalg.norm(w) # orthogonal unit vector

    # check that vectors are indeed orthogonal
    assert np.isclose(np.dot(v, w), 0.)

    # rescale unit vector
    dx, dy = delta * w

    return dx, dy


def simple_test():

    x = np.linspace(-1, 1, 1000)
    y = np.sqrt(1. - x**2)
    path = np.c_[x, y]

    curve = CurvedPatch(path, 0.1, facecolor='red', alpha=0.5)

    fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1)
    ax.add_artist(curve)
    ax.plot(x, y) # plot path for reference
    plt.show()


def complicated_test():

    random_points = np.random.rand(10, 2)

    # Adapted from https://stackoverflow.com/a/35007804/2912349
    import scipy.interpolate as si

    def scipy_bspline(cv, n=100, degree=3, periodic=False):
        """ Calculate n samples on a bspline

            cv :      Array ov control vertices
            n  :      Number of samples to return
            degree:   Curve degree
            periodic: True - Curve is closed
        """
        cv = np.asarray(cv)
        count = cv.shape[0]

        # Closed curve
        if periodic:
            kv = np.arange(-degree,count+degree+1)
            factor, fraction = divmod(count+degree+1, count)
            cv = np.roll(np.concatenate((cv,) * factor + (cv[:fraction],)),-1,axis=0)
            degree = np.clip(degree,1,degree)

        # Opened curve
        else:
            degree = np.clip(degree,1,count-1)
            kv = np.clip(np.arange(count+degree+1)-degree,0,count-degree)

        # Return samples
        max_param = count - (degree * (1-periodic))
        spl = si.BSpline(kv, cv, degree)
        return spl(np.linspace(0,max_param,n))

    x, y = scipy_bspline(random_points, n=1000).T
    path = np.c_[x, y]

    curve = CurvedPatch(path, 0.1, facecolor='red', alpha=0.5)

    fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1)
    ax.add_artist(curve)
    ax.plot(x, y) # plot path for reference
    plt.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    plt.ion()
    simple_test()
    complicated_test()
```

Comment: Part of the problem is surely the non-equal aspect. Can you add `ax.set_aspect("equal")` to the plotting routine and reformulate the question? Or state what the expected output for non-equal aspect would be?

Comment: Evidently, I am having one of my denser days again... Thanks, that was indeed the problem.

Comment: I took this question as incentive to update [the original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42972469/4124317) with a solution subclassing `Line2D`. Now, here you say you want to use a `Polygon`; what exactly would be the motivation for this? I mean a line is really a line and no polygon, so is there any other reason, maybe calculating areas of overlap or so where a polygon is beneficial?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest At the end of the day, I want an arrow, not just a line. I guess I could use lines and just add a patch for the arrow head but having a single artist seems cleaner. Also, deriving from `Polygon` seemed natural, as `FancyArrow` also derives from that class, which is what I am currently using to draw my arrows.

Comment: Fair enough. I would think there might be better options with `FancyArrowPatch` and a linewidth in data coordinates; but of course I might misunderstand the final use case. If you want further help with any of this, you can ping me again.